# How can I write this to use less memory?

Tags: python, pandas, airflow

I have an issue where I'm trying to perform certain tasks in something called Apache Airflow.

Thing is the memory is very limited, and performing this pandas line causes it to evict the task and categorise it as using too much memory.

Is there any way to do this another way without using as much memory with these 2 dataframes?

`arct_df = arct_df[~arct_df.im_uuid.isin(dadge_df.im_uuid)]`

Sample of `arct_df` and assume `dadge_df` has the same columns just different data in the rows.

[image: data]

Comment: Will you please provide a sample of your dataframe?

Comment: done - i've obviously mocked out from the real data

Comment: Do you need to read the whole file in memory? If not, I would look for an option to load one row at a time and only store the rows that meet your `isin()` criterion.

Comment: If your dataframe came from a CSV file, you can process it one row at a time using `csv.DictReader()` instead of `pandas.read_csv()`. But I am baffled, I just reviewed the pandas documentation and could not find an equivalent function in there for reading and processing just one record at a time. There's gotta be a way, it's such an obvious optimization when processing large data sets!

Comment: it's insane isn't it. I feel like i'm losing my sanity with this. you'd think it'd be easy... and it's parquet i need it in, which makes it worse...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use Airflow as a data processing framework, that operation will most likely run better on a database if you have the chance.

See Airflow [best practices](https://www.astronomer.io/guides/dag-best-practices).

Comment: Yep, sadly our infrastructure doesn't have that setup yet.... i'm trying to cache and process in chunks as much as possible. It's painful...